# How to check all the check boxes in a table layout in android

Tags: android, tablelayout

I had placed check boxes and I want to select all the check boxes which was placed in a table layout in android but it doesn't work for me can any one tell me how to do this this is my code for selecting all the check boxes in a table layout:

```
    public class Manual_AC_Fuse_ckt extends Fragment {

        public int []check_box_count = new int[12];
        CheckBox check_box,
            check_box_count[0] = R.id.cb_1;
                    check_box_count[1] = R.id.cb_2;
                    check_box_count[2] = R.id.cb_3;
                    check_box_count[3] = R.id.cb_4;
                    check_box_count[4] = R.id.cb_5;
                    check_box_count[5] = R.id.cb_6;
                    check_box_count[6] = R.id.cb_7;
                    check_box_count[7] = R.id.cb_8;
                    check_box_count[8] = R.id.cb_9;
                    check_box_count[9] = R.id.cb_10;
                    check_box_count[10] = R.id.cb_11;
                    check_box_count[11] = R.id.cb_12;
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 Root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manualmode_ac_fuse_ckt, null);

        table = (TableLayout)Root_view.findViewById(R.id.table_layout_manual_mode);

        registerForContextMenu(table);
        return Root_view;
                @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("OPTIONS");

        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "SELECT ALL");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "DESELECT ALL");
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getTitle()=="SELECT ALL"){
            for(i=0;i<table.getChildCount();i++){

                check_box_2 = (CheckBox)Root_view.findViewById(check_box_count[i]);
                check_box_2.setChecked(true);


            }

            }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Once you get reference to your CheckBox, just call setChecked(boolean value) where boolean true = check and boolean false = uncheck!

Comment: I did that dude but wont work for me @4k3R

Comment: Are you getting any error while calling setChecked() method on the checkbox reference variable?

Comment: my Correction i am using a check box from library dude if  i am  using default check box it works

Comment: Maybe it's a bug associated with the library. Share the name of the library.

Comment: https://github.com/keithellistemp/MaterialWidget this is my library dude @4k3R

Comment: I looked into their code, Their CheckBox class extends from CompoundButton which has a setChecked(boolean checked) method. Are you getting any exception? or error while calling setChecked()?

Comment: No dude no exception occurs But it was not checked thats my problem @4k3R

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check multiple checkboxes in a table layout in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088593/how-to-check-multiple-checkboxes-in-a-table-layout-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getTitle().equals("SELECT ALL")){
        for(i=0;i<table.getChildCount();i++){

            check_box_2 = (CheckBox)Root_view.findViewById(check_box_count[i]);
            check_box_2.setChecked(true);


        }

        }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```